# How to make a custom view's frame match its instrinsic content size

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, intrinsic-content-size

## Custom Label that Resizes According to its Contents

I'm making a label from scratch. (My end purpose is to make a vertical text label for Mongolian script, but for now I am just making a normal horizontal text label as practice.)

As long as there are no length and width constraints, I want my custom label's frame to resize according to its intrinsic content size.

## It Works in IB

In IB everything seems to be working fine when I test a `UILabel`, my custom label (a `UIView` subclass), and a button.

I add top and leading constrains to each of these views but don't set any height or width constraints.

[image]

If I resize them on the storyboard (but still without adding any more constraints)...

[image]

And then choose *Update Frames* for *All Views in View Controller*, the normal label and my custom label both resize properly to their intrinsic content sizes.

[image]

## It Doesn't Work on a Running App

When I change the label text at runtime, though, my custom label's frame is not resizing. (I temporarily added a dark blue border to the text layer to help differentiate it here from the custom label's frame, which is the light blue background color.)

[image]

Clicking "Change text" gives

[image]

As you can see, the text layer frame changed but the custom view's frame didn't.

## Code

This is my custom label class:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class UILabelFromScratch: UIView {

    private let textLayer = CATextLayer()

    @IBInspectable var text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            updateTextLayerFrame()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat = 17 {
        didSet {
            updateTextLayerFrame()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        // Text layer
        textLayer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        textLayer.borderWidth = 1
        textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
        layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
    }

    // MARK: Other methods

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return textLayer.frame.size
    }

    func updateTextLayerFrame() {

        let myAttribute = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize) ]
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text, attributes: myAttribute )
        let size = dimensionsForAttributedString(attrString)

        textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.layer.bounds.origin.x, y: self.layer.bounds.origin.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        textLayer.string = attrString

    }

    func dimensionsForAttributedString(attrString: NSAttributedString) -> CGSize {

        var ascent: CGFloat = 0
        var descent: CGFloat = 0
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        let line: CTLineRef = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)
        width = CGFloat(CTLineGetTypographicBounds(line, &ascent, &descent, nil))

        // make width an even integer for better graphics rendering
        width = ceil(width)
        if Int(width)%2 == 1 {
            width += 1.0
        }

        return CGSize(width: width, height: ceil(ascent+descent))
    }
}
```

And here is the view controller class:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var normalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFromScratch: UILabelFromScratch!

    @IBAction func changeTextButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        normalLabel.text = "Hello"
        labelFromScratch.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

## Question

What is it that `UILabel` does that I am missing in my custom label? I overrode `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return textLayer.frame.size
}
```

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing a single line of code:

```
invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

I added it after updating the text layer frame.

```
func updateTextLayerFrame() {

    // ...

    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.layer.bounds.origin.x, y: self.layer.bounds.origin.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

    // ...
}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/invalidateIntrinsicContentSize) says

> Call this when something changes in your custom view that invalidates
>   its intrinsic content size. This allows the constraint-based layout
>   system to take the new intrinsic content size into account in its next
>   layout pass.

Where I found this solution:

- [Advanced Auto Layout Toolbox](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/)